# No funciona el botón. El botón debería general una tabla de dos filas y dos columnas

Tags: javascript, html

El botón debería general una tabla de dos filas y dos columnas. Como la de la foto.

```js
function genera_tabla() {
  var insertar = ['hi', 'there', 'hello', 'world'];
  var tabla = createElement('tbody');
  var tabla_completa = createElement('table');
  tabla.setAttribute('border', '2');
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    tabla.insertRow(i);
    for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      tabla.rows[i].insertCell(j);
      tabla.rows[i].cells[j] = createTextNode(insertar[i + j]);
    }
  }
  tabla_completa.appendChild(tabla);
  document.body.appendChild(tabla_completa);
}
```

```html
<input onclick="genera_tabla()" type="button" value="Genera una tabla">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El texto que se obliga a introducir existe para que nos cuentes el problema, con qué te has atascado exactamente, lo que has intentado hacer para solucionarlo... Para evitar que se peguen tareas directamente y a esperar las soluciones. Ya que alguien se va a parar a ayudarte al menos que se perciba un mínimo de interés.

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Tenias errores de sintaxis y los he corregido y he añadido css para la tabla.

```js
function genera_tabla() {

            var insertar = ["hi","there","hello","world"];
            var tabla = document.createElement("tbody");
            var tabla_completa = document.createElement("table");
            tabla.setAttribute("border", "2");
            
            for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                tabla.insertRow(i);
                for (let j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                {
                    tabla.rows[i].insertCell(j);
                    tabla.rows[i].cells[j].appendChild(document.createTextNode(insertar[i+j]));
                }
            }
            tabla_completa.appendChild(tabla);
            
            document.body.appendChild(tabla_completa);
        }
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
```

```html
  <input onclick="genera_tabla()" type="button" value="Genera una tabla">
```

Comment: Amigo, para que conozcas el por que de tus votos, evita responder preguntas de mala calidad. Por favor lee [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Jajaja gracias!